# How can I open the webpage corresponding to a complete 256 char+ URL given (not in HYPERLINK form) in a Cell.Value?

Tags: excel, vba, url, hyperlink

I have dynamic composite URLs that include up to 173 different product numbers each.

The composite URLs are custom compiled from an imported list of up to 1000 product numbers using conditional text formulas. I capped each URL at 2040 characters to fit my browser's max URL character limit, but these create issues with Excel's 256 character hyperlink limit.

I get invalid process with any VBA based solution and #value! with any formula-based solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Following @ComputerVersher's advice, I implemented the code found at https://www.devhut.net/2018/02/01/vba-open-a-url-in-firefox-chrome/ and called it with     `Call OpenURL(Range("K16").Value, InternetExplorer)`

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have a URL in cell `A1`.

In a standard code module add this routine:

```
Sub OpenWebpage(url$)
    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink url
End Sub
```

Now call it like this:

```
OpenWebpage Range("A1")
```

The above solution will use your computer system's default web-browser.

---

To open the URL in Internet Explorer by direct automation use this procedure:

```
Sub OpenWebpageInIE(url$)
    With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(url)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220248/discussion-on-answer-by-excel-hero-using-vba-how-can-i-open-the-webpage-correspo).